# Force Swift Package Manager to honour Package.resolved

Tags: swift-package-manager

I am trying to use Swift Package manager to update my dependencies locally to match those in the `Package.resolved` file.

For example, when I update my dependencies I run `swift package update`, which updates the `Package.resolved` file, which I then commit. When I pull this new commit on to a computer that has an existing `.build` directory with the old versions of the dependencies I would like to update the local versions to the one in `Package.resolved`.

I was expecting `swift package resolve` to do this, but instead it updates the `Package.resolved` according to the `.build/dependencies-state.json`.

The obvious solution is to delete the `.build` directory, but this means the dependencies are recompiled every time, which can be slow on CI.

I want the equivalent of `bundle install`, `yarn install`, or `carthage boostrap`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be a bug, and I have opened a [bug in the Swift JIRA](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10718).